# VBA Input to Hidden Input field that has a Lookup

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to automate input into a members booking system. There is a field that I need to enter a name into that has a lookup attached to it.

For instance, I would type Smith into the field and all the members that begin with Smith would appear and allow me to click on one of them.

So, I get as far as the form and can get all the values that have been manually input, but I cant work out how to interact with the field itself in order to enter a new value.

```
  Set elements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  Debug.Print "7 - " & elements(7).Name & " : " & elements(7).Value
  Debug.Print "8 - " & elements(8).Name & " : " & elements(8).Value
  Debug.Print "9 - " & elements(9).Name & " : " & elements(9).Value
  Debug.Print "10 - " & elements(10).Name & " : " & elements(10).Value
```

Gives me the following:

```
7 - Player1Name : Guegan, Mr Julian
8 - Player1ID : 1485741
9 - Player2Name : 
10 - Player2ID :
```

I want to enter the Player2Name and have the webpage perform the lookup.

I have tried setting `elements(9).Value` and/or `elements(10).Value`, but the page ignores it. I have even attempted resorting to Sendkeys, but no success.

[image: Screenshot of the html]

Comment: I would *strongly* advise against automating Internet Explorer, of all things, with VBA, of all things, for this task. The first choice would be to put data into the database directly. If that's not an option, I'd try to figure out the HTTP requests that are sent by this form, and replicate those, instead of trying to automate a browser. If that's not an option, either, I would try to use an established browser automation framework such as Selenium with a modern browser. The last option is the most complex one, so I'd really try to avoid it.

Comment: Besides, how would you automate "picking a user from a dynamically generated list" in a reliable fashion? When you tyoe "Smith", and ten names pop up, how would your code know which is the correct one?

Comment: Thanks. It isnt an option to input to the database directly, nor is it an option to replicate the HTTP requests, so I will need to go with Selenium, which I am happy enough spend the time figuring out, but will I come across the same issue of not being able to input into the hidden field.?

Comment: That's interesting - why isn't it an option to replicate the HTTP requests?

Comment: Coding ignorance primarily...

Comment: Then if you are going to learn something new, figure out how the website interacts with the server. Check which requests are being sent and received using the browser's developer tools (those that open with F12). That's probably one or more GET requests as the dropdown is populated, and a POST request when you send the form. You might find that re-creating those requests from within a programming language is *much* easier than learning how to automate a browser with a library you don't know.

Comment: For the lookup field, try to set the exact value that the user can select from the populated options. after that try to fire the change event of that element. For the hidden field, first, try to change the field type to 'text' and set the value. After that fire, the change event of the element may help you to assign the value properly.

Comment: Deepak - thank you. That worked perfectly. It was firing the change event that I was overlooking.

Comment: I will post my comment as an answer to this question. You can try to accept it as an answer. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as referred to in the comments was to fire the change event which then went off and retrieves some hidden information(user id etc) and submits to the database.

Answer (score 0):

For the lookup field, try to set the exact value that the user can select from the populated options. after that try to fire the change event of that element.

For the hidden field, first, try to change the field type to 'text' and set the value. After that fire, the change event of the element may help you to assign the value properly.